# Title does not show when i share my website link

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have used meta title,image and everything still this sql error statement shows in title.
This sql error came when i first developed my website and faced some error. Now my website has no problem, runnuing smoothly but this sql statement always shows when i share the link with someone.

```
    <meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.example.com" />
    <meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title"              content="My Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"        content="" />
    <meta property="og:image"              content="images/teer-result.jpg" />
```

[image]

Comment: visit the link you shared in incognito mode (Ctrl + Shift + N). you will understand the issue

Comment: Note that the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

You should visit your link. Then view source and check what' value is really set in the property="og:title". It will probably shed some light on the error.

If it looks good then it's likely Facebook cached a previous erroneous value. In that case try using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to fetch a fresh copy and confirm.